# Can't seem to get a live pen to boot on my laptop

Tags: 12.04, boot, intel, menu

Specs:
989,5 MB ram
Intel atom CPU N2600 @ 1.60GHz x 4
Mesa X11
32 bit flavor
312.2 GB
Laptop's outside is carbon fiber.

Tried putting a live usb pen with fedora in it,but doesn't seem to show the Pen. And it doesn't even have a boot menu! How can i make it boot from the pen?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you need to change your computers boot priorities
on startup press something like f1, f8 depends on laptop, and see if you can change your booting priority to put USB in first place

Comment: Only gets me the GRUB.

Comment: Do you mean to say, you are able to see the GRUB loader?